# Meaning of "mints"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, adjectives, slang

Context ([New York Times](http://travel.nytimes.com/2010/06/20/travel/20hotels.html)),

> **MINTS** An organic fudge brownie awaits you in the room, along with a personalized welcome letter...

First, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not (I'm wondering if *mints* here is a shortening for *mint aspects* [nice/good aspects].?), but these are what I found on the Internet,

> [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mint)
>   : 4.(slang) Very good.
>
> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mint): 1. Nice.  2. Cool

If I'm correct, I would like to know how common this word (mint adj.) is used in American English?

By the way, is this word used in BE as well?  Because I also read this,

> [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=mint): 2.Expression used in The North Of England meaning good

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that the term "mints" is actually referring to the nice things that hotels do for you. In the past, nice hotels would leave an edible mint on your pillow every night. So, the review uses "mints" to mean the extras provided by the hotel.

Answer (score 2):

In the article, the paragraph heading **MINTS** refers to two things:

1. (Symbolic) All the amenities that the hotel provides (mentioned in the paragraph).
2. (Literal) The actual "mints" that hotels often leave on your pillow when you first arrive.

In this case, the hotel has left an "organic fudge brownie," instead of the traditional piece of mint chocolate candy.

**Definition**: A *mint chocolate* or *chocolate mint* (sometimes called simply "mints" in the plural) is a type of candy that has a mint-flavored filling on the inside, with a chocolate candy shell on the outside.

*Example Usage*: "Ooh, you have a big bag of *mints*!  Can have have one of those *chocolate mints*?

Note that the word *mint* in this usage refers not to the plant/herb, but to any type of candy – soft or hard – that has mint flavoring.  A chocolate mint is just a variant of the standard mint candy.

Comment: What do you mean by "(chocolate candy)"?

Comment: A mint left by a hotel is usually chocolate mint, a chocolate candy that has mint flavoring.

Comment: Thanks @thursdaysgeek, I was just writing it up! :) Matt: I added a definition to the answer above.